# Writing ListBox sections and the corresponding TextBoxes to a INI file

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, foreach, listbox

I have a ListBox (ListBox1) with multiple sections, for example:
Excel
Word
Outlook

When I click on a section it has multiple corresponding textboxes, for example:

Item1
txtbxCommandline c:\word.exe
txtbxShortcut 1
txtbxVersion 14

Item2
txtbxCommandline c:\excel.exe
txtbxShortcut 2
txtbxVersion 12

Item3
txtbxCommandline c:\PowerPoint.exe
txtbxShortcut 2
txtbxVersion 11

I use the following code to write the section name and the values of the textboxes to a file:

```
For Each item In ListBox1.Items
writeIni(file, item, CommandLine, txtbxCommandLine.Text)
writeIni(file, item, Shortcut, txtbxShortcut.Text)
writeIni(file, item, Version, txtbxVersion.Text)
```

File is the INI file
Item is the Section
Version is the Title
Txtbx is the Value

The code only writes the first value (in this case the C:\Word.exe value) to 3 sections instead of 3 sections with different values.

My question is, how can I get the different values in the INI file instead of 3 times the same value?

Comment: You have three textbox that contains the values for the same item. Of course you write the same value three times. You need something to store the different values for the three items.

Comment: You either need to have separate text boxes for each section, which you show and hide accordingly, or you need to store the values for each section in some sort of data structure in memory.